# Why does android debug build is mostly used in Appium automation testing than the android release build?

Tags: testing, build, automation, appium, apache-cordova

**Android debug build apk** is mostly used for testing; is there any problem if I use **android release build apk** in Appium testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Release build also for Appium automation but if the locator value protected by the release build we have to change to debug build . 
So that its easy to write reliable script with right locators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either build when testing this issue with using a production build for testing is performing automated tests on production is not good practice. If something were to go wrong your automation could potentially dos your production servers. Many other issues can also arise, through proper setup of the app package you are using you should be able to run on either or builds. I for example am running on both a dev and qa environment with no problems.

Comment: That's why you should mock your data, you're not supposed to test your backend within your react native test